# Ruby: Merging nested array between each other depending on a condition

Tags: ruby, array-merge

What would be the best way to merge arrays nested in an array that shares at least an element ? Here's an example:

```
some_method([[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5]])
#=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
some_method([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [5,6]])
#=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: what should happen when the array is `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5], [2, 6]]`?

Comment: I'd like it to merge (and call uniq on) all elements sharing at list one value
=> [[1, 2, 3, 6], [4, 5]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would work:

```
def some_method(arrays)
  h = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
  arrays.each do |array|
    tmp = h.values_at(*array).push(array).inject(:|)
    tmp.each { |k| h[k] = tmp }
  end
  h.values | h.values
end
```

Examples:

```
some_method([[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5]])          #=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]    
some_method([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [5, 6]])  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6]]    
some_method([[1, 3], [3, 4], [2, 5], [4, 5]])  #=> [[1, 3, 4, 2, 5]]
```

I'm using a hash `h` to store the array that correspond to a given element. The hash returns `[]` if a key doesn't exist.

After inserting `[1, 2]`, the hash looks like this:

```
{
  1 => [1, 2],
  2 => [1, 2]
}
```

When inserting `[2, 3]`, the arrays for `2` and `3` are fetched via:

```
h.values_at(2, 3)
#=> [[1, 2], []]
```

then `[2, 3]` itself is added:

```
h.values_at(2, 3).push([2, 3])
#=> [[1, 2], [], [2, 3]]
```

and everything is [`|`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-7C)-ed:

```
h.values_at(2, 3).push([2, 3]).inject(:|)
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

This result is stored in `tmp`. It becomes the new value for the contained keys:

```
tmp.each { |k| h[k] = tmp }
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
h[1] = tmp
h[2] = tmp
h[3] = tmp
```

Afterwards, `h` looks like this:

```
{
  1 => [1, 2, 3],
  2 => [1, 2, 3],
  3 => [1, 2, 3]
}
```

At the end, the distinct values are returned via `h.values | h.values`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you use 'h.values | h.values' instead of '#uniq' ?

Comment: @DavidB. no, not really. Maybe it's even faster to compare by object identity, i.e. `h.values.uniq(&:object_id)`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you use 'h.values | h.values' instead of 'h.values & h.values'  (or `h.invert.keys`)?

Comment: @CarySwoveland the only reason is that I've used `|` earlier in the method to remove duplicates.

Comment: Yes, I had noticed. Nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

arr.map(&:dup).sort.each_with_object([]) do |a, memo|
  (idx = memo.index { |m| !(m & a).empty? }) ? memo[idx] |= a : memo << a
end
#⇒ [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

or, more expressive:

```
arr.map(&:dup).sort.each_with_object([]) do |a, memo|
  (memo.detect { |m| !(m & a).empty? } << a).
    flatten!.uniq! rescue memo << a
end
```

the most precise solution, that works for any permutations, but consumes more time:

```
loop.inject(arr.map(&:dup)) do |acc|
  result = (acc.each_with_object([]) do |a, memo|
    (idx = memo.index { |m| !(m & a).empty? }) ? memo[idx] |= a : memo << a 
  end)
  result == acc ? (break result) : result
end
```

Comment: This returns `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3], [3, 4], [5, 6]]`, not `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6]]`

Comment: @TomLord it returns `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6]]`, run it and make sure yourself.

Comment: But it returns `[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4]]` for `arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [2, 3]]`. You can't assume consecutive pairs.

Comment: Ahhh ok sorry, I was checking the value of `arr`, not the value of the enumerator. (It's still worth noting, however, that you mutated the original object!)

Comment: @Stefan indeed, fixed with `.sort`.

Comment: @TomLord added `.dup` to both variants to avoid mutating original array, thanks.

Comment: @mudasobwa Your solution is still fundamentally flawed. It needs to be a recursive method. For example, consider the input: `[[1, 3], [3, 4], [2, 5], [4, 5]]`  -- your code will return `[[1, 3, 4, 5], [2, 5]]`, not `[[1,2,3,4,5]]`

Comment: @TomLord ok, for cumbersome permutations `while` loop does the trick, there is still no need for recursion. Updated an answer.

Comment: Yeah, my point was that you'd need to repeat the procedure indefinitely until the result stabilised. Not necessarily with recursion, although it does seem like the most logic approach to me.

Comment: @Stefan `while` returns `nil`, the `result` is stored in `res` variable. Updated.

Comment: @mudasobwa are you sure it works? I keep getting `nil` for `res`.

Comment: @Stefan yes, I am sure it works here (ruby 2.1.8.) What input do you test it on?

Comment: @Stefan indeed, thanks. I seem to have `res` already set and was just re-running the snippet without changing anything. `while` loop is evil: I rewrote it with normal `loop` and now it seems to work smoothly. Sorry for bringing mess. http://ideone.com/2lIaX1

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very simple approach. The steps are as follows.

1. Beginning with an array `a = arr.map(&:uniq)`, `arr` being the initial array of arrays, look for two arrays of `a` that share an element, among all combinations of two arrays of `a`. If none are found, return `a` (fini!); else go to step 2.
2. If `a[i]` and `a[j]` are found to contain a common element, `a[i]` becomes `a[i].concat(a[j]).uniq` and `a[j]` is deleted.
3. Repeat #1.

```
def group_unique(arr)
  a = arr.map(&:uniq)
  loop do
    (_,i),(_,j) = a.each_with_index.to_a.combination(2).find {|(a,_),(b,_)|(a&b).any?}
    return a if i.nil?
    a[i] = a[i].concat(a.delete_at(j)).uniq
  end
end

arr = [[1,2], [5,6], [2,3], [4,5], [4,1], [7,8], [11,13], [8,10]]
group_unique(arr)
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 10], [11, 13]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little verbose, but here is a **recursive** method that solves the problem properly:

```
def merge_shared_elements(list) 
  changed = false 
  result = list.each_with_object([]) do |item, new_list| 
    if existing_item = new_list.find {|new_item| !(new_item & item).empty?} 
      existing_item.concat(item).uniq! 
      changed = true 
    else 
      new_list << item 
    end 
  end 

  changed ? merge_shared_elements(result) : result 
end
```

This will keep re-iterating through the list, so the order of inputs is irrelevant.